# ASP.NET file upload access denied error (ASP.NET Development server not IIS)

Tags: asp.net

How to give rights to asp.net dev server to accesss paths in file upload?
I am getting Access to the path is denied error.

Comment: do you mean iis express ?

Comment: no, its the asp.net development server in visual studio.